# android : customer List Adatper + ArrayList

Tags: android

Team,

Could you please help me debug the issue?

ActivityAdapter activityAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(this,activityList);
        Log.d("list", "List Display - 1");

```
    setListAdapter( activityAdapter );
    Log.d("List", "list done");
```

It's throwing exception at the time of setListAdapter,

05-01 16:59:15.996: WARN/dalvikvm(251): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-01 16:59:15.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.antennasoftware.xml/com.antennasoftware.xml.XMLParsing}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2454)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at com.antennasoftware.xml.XMLParsing.onCreate(XMLParsing.java:36)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-01 16:59:16.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(251):     ... 11 more

class ActivityList extends LinearLayout {

```
public ActivityList(Context context, ActivityBean activityBean) {
    super(context);

    this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    ListView listView = new ListView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams idParams = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //cityParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

    TextView idColumn = new TextView( context );
    idColumn.setText( activityBean.getActivityId() );
    idColumn.setTextSize(14f);
    idColumn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    listView.addView( idColumn, idParams);       

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams accountNameParams = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    TextView accountNameView = new TextView(context);
    accountNameView.setText( activityBean.getAccountName() );
    accountNameView.setTextSize( 14f );
    accountNameView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    listView.addView( accountNameView, accountNameParams);            

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams typeParams = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(25, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //ImageView skyControl = new ImageView( context );
    TextView typeView = new TextView(context);
    typeView .setText( activityBean.getAccountName() );
    typeView.setTextSize( 14f );
    typeView .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    listView.addView( typeView, typeParams );
    addView(listView);
}
```

}

public class ActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
public ActivityAdapter(Context context, List activityList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activityList = activityList;
}

private Context context;
private List activityList;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return activityList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ActivityBean activity = (ActivityBean) activityList.get(position);
    return new ActivityList(this.context, activity );

}
```

}

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You're using a ListActivity, which requires you to have a ListView in your content XML with the id "@id:android/list"

See the [documentation for ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
>   content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Does your XML view file contain a proper id field in the format: `android:id="@id/android:list` for the corresponding ListView tag?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: public class XMLParsing extends ListActivity implements Runnable {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 ActivityBean activityBean;
 ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Log.d("parse", "parsing done");
  activityList = retrieveFromDatabase();
  Log.d("list", "List Display");
     ActivityAdapter activityAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(this,activityList);
     Log.d("list", "List Display - 1");
   
     setListAdapter( activityAdapter );

Comment: @Ram: you should post this in your question. But indeed, your ListView id tag is ill-formed. It should be "@id/android:list".

Comment: This issue got resolved. removed setcontentview and it started working fine. Thanks everyone for your help